# Rails Form Objects with multiple nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

[7 Patterns to Refactor Fat ActiveRecord Models](http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/) - here is a great article about different refactoring approaches using PORO. Under the 3rd caption there is a Form Object pattern, which I really liked and already implemented in one of the projects. There is only an example using one nested resource, but I would like to implement this pattern for multiple nested resources. Maybe someone here had already dealt with this? I don't necessarily need any code examples, just the basic idea would be fine.

**Update**

Consider this example. I have two models.

```
class Company
  has_many :users

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :users
end

class User
  belongs_to :company
end
```

In case of one nested user for company using Form Object Pattern I would write the following:

```
<%= form_for @company_form do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :user_name %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Form Object

```
class CompanyForm
  include Virtus

  extend ActiveModel::Naming
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  attr_accessor :company, :user

  def user
    @user ||= company.users.build
  end

  def company
    @company ||= Company.new
  end

  def submit(params={})
    company.name = params[:name]
    user.name = params[:user_name]
    persist!
  end

  private

  def persist!
    company.save!
    user.save!
  end
end
```

But what if I have a form, where a company with multiple users can be created. The usual approach is to write it like this, using [nested_form](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form):

```
<%= nested_form_for @company do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= fields_for :users, do |user_form| %>
    <%= user.form.text_field :name %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.link_to_add "Add a user", :users %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

What I am asking is how do I implement that Form Object Pattern in this case?

Comment: This is not really a question, so it will be hard to answer.  Can you please post some code and ask a more specific question?  Thanks.

Comment: This is a great question, that I am trying to find more info on. Did you ever resolve this issue with form objects?

Comment: Haven't yet, but the first thing that comes to my mind is to make a custom link_to_add/remove helper (like one in nested_form gem) where a new instance of form object should be constructed instead of a new model.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

the rails [fields_for](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4fdde75b17734b26cba99d83bf06e175c896df34/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb#L1827) helper [checks](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4fdde75b17734b26cba99d83bf06e175c896df34/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb#L1827) for a method in this format: `#{association_name}_attributes=`

so, if you add this method to CompanyForm:

```
def users_attributes=(users_attributes)
  # manipulate attributes as desired...
  @company.users_attributes= users_attributes
end

def users
  company.users
end
```

the `fields_for` generators will generate the nested users fields for a CompanyForm as if it were a Company. the above could be rewritten as a delegation since nothing is happening in the methods:

```
  delegate :users, :users_attributes=, :to => :company, :prefix => false, :allow_nil => false
```